# Laravel 5.1 でのコーディングスタイル

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.1 を利用するプロジェクトについて、プロジェクト内で決めているコーディングルールやコミュニティ標準のルールがあれば教えていただきたいです。

というのも新規プロジェクトでLaravelを利用しているのですが、機能が豊富過ぎかつ公式のリファレンスがいまいち良い物がなく、何をするにもGoogle経由でドキュメントを検索という状態になってしまいまして、

幸い[Facadeのチートシート](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/)は見つけたので、ヘルパー禁止・ファサードをできるだけ使うなどの規約にしたいと思っているのですが、コミュニティ標準の規約があればそれに従いたいです。

PSRに従うのは当然として、それ以外に何かあればシェアをお願いします。